# No suitable driver found error (SQLite in Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, sqlite, jdbc

High school teacher here.  Have students working on programs that integrate an SQLite database with a java program and I have gotten this connection to work on my computer but have a couple of students who keep getting this error message.  Below is my code and I have made sure that theirs is identical (other than database path of course)

```
private Connection conn(){
        
    
        Connection conn = null;
        
        try {

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/Users/j.oswald_daa/eclipse-workspace/GroceryStoreFS/bin/GSDatabase.db");
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            
    
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection");
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        
        System.out.println("Connected");
        return conn;
        
    }
```

After scouring previous posts regarding this and trying all solutions I have made sure of the following

The proper jar file with the driver has been added to the classpath (have tried multiple versions)
The path to the database matches the location of the database

All other settings that I am familiar with are the same on both computers

Most solutions involved loading the class using Class.forName() but that solution does not work and appears to be unnecessary after JDBC 4.0 which is what by me and my students are using.

Here are links to screenshots of the stack track and .classpath files

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gosfp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCe0F.png)

Comment: Maybe those students where it is not working have a `module-info.java` in the default package which should better deleted in this case (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_, but then make sure that it contains the required [`requires ...;` statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System#Properties_of_modules)). Otherwise, show the stack trace and the `.classpath` file from those students.

Comment: Yes I have previously discovered the issues with the module-info file and have made sure it has been deleted from their project.  Will post the requested items once I have seen the students in class today

Comment: Ok images showing stack trace and classpath file have been added to original post.  The classpath file matches mine with the exception of the order of the "lib" and "con" statements

Comment: Please post exceptions and code as code-formatted **text**, not as screenshots.

Comment: Do you use maven as build tool or what? You should check the pom.xml and make sure to add proper dependency on the sqlite. Your classpath conf is way too old school